# Remove newline characters from pandas series of lists

Tags: python, pandas, newline, python-re

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that contains two columns, one of tags containing numbers and the other with a list containing string elements.

Dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'tags': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 
    'elements': {
        0: ['\n☒', '\nANNUAL REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15(d) OF THE SECURITIES EXCHANGE ACT OF 1934 '],
        1: ['', ''],
        2: ['\n', '\nFor the Fiscal Year Ended June 30, 2020'],
        3: ['\n', '\n'],
        4: ['\n', '\nOR']
    }
})
```

I am trying to remove all instances of `\n` from any element in all the lists from the column `elements` but I'm really struggling to do so. My solution was to use a nested loop and `re.sub()` to trying and replace these but it has done nothing (granted this is a horrible solution). This was my attempt:

```py
for ls in range(len(page_table.elements)):
    for st in range(len(page_table.elements[i])):
        page_table.elements[i][st] = re.sub('\n', '', page_table.elements[i][st])
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please read this: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) e.g. use `df[['tags', 'elements']].iloc[:5].to_dict()`

Comment: You'll need to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (maybe many times, depending on nesting) and then [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the `\n` values. But you should update this to be a better example that can be copied and pasted easily.

Comment: @Andreas please find the updated output

Comment: @geds133, thank you, unfortunatly they sample data is not copy pastable, because the html is not in quotes. So it is difficult to reproduce your problem. I would suggest that you (manually?) create simplified copy/pastable sample data as input and the expected output for it. Otherwise we need more time to prepare sample data then to solve the question itself.

Comment: @geds133 that dict doesn't match the lists that were in the `tags` column in your first revision

Comment: @Andreas the column `tags` is not the important column here and so I have dropped it from the output. The focus here is cleaning the lists in elements.

Comment: @Alex tags here could be anything. Take an example of a series with a single integer in each row. The focus here is on `elements`

Comment: i've hopefully added the construction of the df to the bottom of the post @geds133 pls check it.

Comment: @Andreas I have updated the output to be a much simpler version. Hope this helps

Comment: @Alex I have updated the output to be a much simpler version. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and then [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the `\n` values.
You can leave out the `.groupby(level=0).agg(list)` to not put them back into lists, though this will have a different shape to the original DataFrame.

```py
df["elements"] = (
    df["elements"]
    .explode()
    .str.replace(r"\n", "", regex=True)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(list)
)
```

Which outputs:

```
0    [☒, ANNUAL REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15...
1                                                 [, ]
2          [, For the Fiscal Year Ended June 30, 2020]
3                                                 [, ]
4                                               [, OR]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also possible:

```
df['elements'] = df['elements'].map(lambda x: [y.replace('\n', '') for y in x])


0    [☒, ANNUAL REPORT PURSUANT TO SECTION 13 OR 15...
1                                                 [, ]
2          [, For the Fiscal Year Ended June 30, 2020]
3                                                 [, ]
4                                               [, OR]
```